How can i aggregate a JSON using ADF Dataflow?
i'm using ADF for the fist time to take datas from a CSV and elaborate them in a JSON
i have a structure that is like:
|father |date |record1 |record2 |...|recordn |
|father |date2|record1A|record2A|...|recordnA|
|father |date3|record1B|record2B|...|recordnA|
|father2|date |record1 |record2 |...|recordn |
|father2|date2|record1A|record2B|...|recordnA|

the json structure i want is something like:
{
    "father": "father"
    "Report": {
        "Date": "2021-11-25",
        "Values": {
            "record1": "record1",
            "record2": "record2",
            "record3": "record3",
            "recordn": "recordn"
        }
    },
    "Report": {
        "Date": "2021-11-26",
        "Values": {
            "record1": "record1A",
            "record2": "record2A",
            "record3": "record3A",
            "recordn": "recordnA"
        }
    },
    "Report": {
        "Date": "2021-11-27",
        "Values": {
            "record1": "record1B",
            "record2": "record2B",
            "record3": "record3B",
            "recordn": "recordnB"
        }
    }
}
{
    "father": "father2"
    "Report": {
        "Date": "2021-11-25",
        "Values": {
            "record1": "record1",
            "record2": "record2",
            "record3": "record3",
            "recordn": "recordn"
        }
    },
    "Report": {
        "Date": "2021-11-26",
        "Values": {
            "record1": "record1A",
            "record2": "record2A",
            "record3": "record3A",
            "recordn": "recordnA"
        }
    }
}

Where:

the number of record is fixe for every subgroup, and is one for each column of the csv
every line of the csv is a unique combination fo father+date so it cannot exist two rows with different values in records columns for the same father and date

I'm using a DataFlow Derived columns (please note the screenshot below to see the data flow process) to try to get somewhere. i was able to generate a json with this structure
{
    "STRUCTURE": {
        "FATHER": "FATHER"
        "Report": {
            "Date": "2021-11-03 00:00:00.0000000",
            "Values": {
                "record1": "record1A",
                "record2": "record2A",
                "record3": "record3A",
                "recordn": "recordnA"
            }
        }
    }
}

for each line of the csv.
is not clear for me how to create a structure to have a sort of "group by" on my father column. i dont know if i need to change something in my import source step of adf or in the derived column. the thing is that obviusly derived clumns generates a column with the structure i write. so a json for everyline. i don know if there is a way to aggregate.

i'm open to totally change my prospective and do not use dataflows at all. i know how to use parameters but i don't know how to implement it there
please give me some suggestions

To transform the pipe delimited text file as nested Json, follow the below approach.

Take the source transformation and take the source dataset in it.

Take the derived column transformation and add a new column named Values. The expression for the column Values is,
@(each(match(startsWith(name,'record')), $$ = $$))


Take another derived column transformation and add a column named Report. The expression for that column is @(date=date,   Values=Values)


Then take aggregate transformation and group the data by father column.



This way, you can aggregate into Nested JSON.

Thank you! i've checked your comment as a solution even if at the end it generates one file for each group in the aggregation while my goal is more to have just one file. still this was very illuminating. so thank you. if you have a fast solution to have just one file thank you :)
Now i'm trying with: derivedcolumn1, derivedcolumn2, aggregation, derivedcolumn3 (that relates @(father = father, report = report)), select (of just this column) but i still get one file for each father

In sink settings, you need to give output to a single file and in partition, select single partition.  screenshot1 screenshot2

EDIT: i found that i can have the output i wanted by changing the sink option. so your response is perfect. thank you so much
